# How can I satisfy a django.contrib.markup.templatetags.markup import restructuredtext in django 1.6?

Tags: django, importerror, restructuredtext

Wondering which restructured package most of you use in django 1.5+?

```
from django.contrib.markup.templatetags.markup import restructuredtext
```

Returns:

```
ImportError ...
No module named markup.templatetags.markup
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.5-alpha-1/#django-utils-markup

Comment: You can use https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-markwhat, which is a drop-in replacement for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the `django.utils.markup` was deprecated in 1.5 and removed in 1.6. The Python implementation of the reStructuredText markup lives in the docutils package. That is the implementation that Django <= 1.5 used.

The easiest way to install docutils is using pip:

```
pip install docutils
```

You can find the old `django.utils.markup` implementation in the 1.5.x branch on Djangos github repo:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/contrib/markup/templatetags/markup.py#L76

Answer (score 1):

This is an addon to the answer by @jbub:

When you have an old Django application and you want to continue using markup, follow these steps:

- Delete `django.contrib.markup` from `INSTALLED_APPS` (in the file `settings.py`
- Add a directory `templatetags` to your application
- Copy the file `markup.py` from https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/contrib/markup/templatetags/markup.py#L76 to `templatetags`
- touch a file `__init__.py` in the `templatetags` directoy
- Start over your webserver and see it working again.

Note that this procedure keeps your old application working. However, the deprecation of `django.contrib.markup` came for a reason: There were security concerns over possible cross-site scripting attacks using markdown. You are on your own to deal with this problem.

Comment: Hi, how can I change a web site that was using `django.contrib.markup` to a new way that replaces all functionalities implemented in that deprecated package? 
Using `docutils` ?